# Is this Syntax correct for python insert operation for mysql? I got error - TypeError: 'str' object is not callable?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x

```
cmd="insert into People(ID,Name,Age,Gender,CriminalRecords)values("+str(Id)+","+str(Name)+","+str(Age)+","+str(Gender)+","+str(Criminal)+")"
```

Answer (score 0):

The values that are strings need quotes around them.

But it's better to use a query with parameters rather than concatenating variables.

```
cmd="insert into People(ID,Name,Age,Gender,CriminalRecords)values(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"
cursor.execute(cmd, (Id, Name, Age, Gender, Criminal))
conn.commit()
```

Replace `cursor` and `conn` with the actual variables containing your cursor and connection objects.